# Cryptographic operations without acces to private key (like in Android keystore)

Tags: java, security, encryption, keystore, android-keystore

I read a little about [Android keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html). What's interesting for me that such keystore allows using cryptographic opeations (like content signing and ciphering) without direct access to private key stored in a keystore. The doc says:

> Android Keystore system protects key material from unauthorized use. Firstly, Android Keystore mitigates unauthorized use of key material outside of the Android device by preventing extraction of the key material from application processes and from the Android device as a whole

I would like to have similar solution in backend web application. The most important for me is to have forbidden direct access to private key from java process. In fact my application process doesn't need it because it only needs to sign content when sending back to the user.

I was looking in KeyStore java api but found nothing or missed something important.

Is such approach possible using standard java KeyStore?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. `KeyStore.getInstance(type, provider)` returns a KeyStore object with a specific implementation of a `Provider`. Using a provider that encapsulate the usage of the private key without exposing the key content is perfectly possible. This is how cryptographic providers based on hardware, such as USB or HSM, work. I do not know if any software cryptographic provider provides this mode of operation

Comment: `process doesn't need it because it only needs to sign content` you need the private key to sign any content. If you really want to prevent the app accessing the key material itself in the backend, you need some kind of HSM (hardware security module) which will do the signing itself.